# remove duplicates in csv with quoted field and embedded commas

Tags: bash, csv, sorting, duplicates

I have a rather large csv, some 5 gb, which has entries like so:

```
"8976897","this is the abstract text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23423","this is the subject text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23","this is the full text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"3443","this is the subject text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
```

the second column when eyeballed show a lot of exact duplicates. I would like to remove these. my questions are:

```
[1] is `sort` the correct tool for this job?
[2] how do I ask sort to work only on the second column?
[3] does sort find duplicates (via -u flag) anywhere on the file or just immediately next line duplicates?
```

I tried this:

```
sort -u infile > outfile
```

and it seems to work, but the file is large so I am unable to check if this has realy done what I had wanted it to do, since nowhere in the command line did I specify to operate on the second column.

apologies if they are daft questions.

Comment: Try:   `sort -u -t, -k2 file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data has quoted fields with embedded commas, a simple tool like `sort` isn't suitable for this task. You need something that natively understands the CSV format.

Here's a perl one-liner that skips printing lines whose second column has already been printed once (In other words, it only prints the first entry if there are duplicates):

```bash
$ perl -MText::CSV_XS -e '
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary=>1, always_quote=>1});
    while (my $rec = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
      $csv->say(*STDOUT, $rec) unless $seen{$rec->[1]}++
    }' input.csv
"8976897","this is the abstract text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23423","this is the subject text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23","this is the full text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
```

It does rely on the non-standard [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) module, available through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client.

---

Warning: Blatant self-promotion ahead.

A similar approach, using my [`tawk` utility](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk), an `awk`-like program built around `tcl`, with a CSV-aware input mode:

```bash
$ tawk -csv 'line { if {![info exists seen($F(2))]} { set seen($F(2)) 1; print }}' input.csv
"8976897","this is the abstract text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23423","this is the subject text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23","this is the full text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
```

Comment: thank you. I will use your utility :) I just relaised that the first column does not contain any double quotes (second column does) - I guess your snippet for tawk still works?

Comment: @JohnJ Nah, for just digits like your sample, that field doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: thanks @Shawn. running your utility to dedupe second column of a 6gb csv RN. :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think [choose](https://github.com/jagprog5/choose) is the tool for this workload (I'm the author).

Here's the solution:

```bash
$ cat file_contents | choose -u --field '^[^,]*+\K.*+'
"8976897","this is the abstract text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23423","this is the subject text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
"23","this is the full text of, some document, and can pretty much contain anything"
```

This leaves first instances of lines with uniqueness only looking at the section matched by the field arg. See the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/cEIxaJ/). gnu sort can't do this, since it can only match contents between commas but your data field can itself contain commas.